# Ajax url path works fine locally, but fails on production with "404 fine not found" error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, server

I have this java-script function:

```
function test() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data:{},
        url : 'testApplication.aspx/GetResult',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
             alert("successful");
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(xhr.textStatus);
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

When I run it locally, it works fine and I get the expected result in my html drop down menu. But when I publish it to production and run the code from production, I get 404 file not found error. I think the problem is in the url path that is not accessible from server.

I also tried "url: '@Url.Content("~/testApplication.aspx/GetResult")' but it did not work.

Any ideas how can I fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: Does the URL 'testApplication.aspx/GetResult' load with a 404 on production when accessed normally, eg through a browser?

Comment: @squaretastic Yes when I go to the production website and add the 'testApplication.aspx/GetResult' to id, it gives 404 error

Comment: Sounds like this is an issue with the URL itself, not your js.  I'd start by checking any error logs you have on the server where the URL isn't working properly to determine the cause.